# Undefined reference to web::json::value::object even if json.h included

Tags: c++, casablanca

I have a code that looks like this:

```
void handle_get(http_request request)
{
   TRACE(L"\nhandle GET\n");

   std::vector< std::pair< utility::string_t, json::value > > answer;

   for(auto const & p : dictionary)
   {
      answer.push_back(std::make_pair(p.first, json::value(p.second)));
   }

   request.reply(status_codes::OK, json::value::object(answer));
};
```

And I get an

```
undefined reference to `web::json::value::object(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, web::json::value>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, web::json::value> > >, bool)'
```

I do not understand why doesn't it see that `answer` has no `std::string`?

---

```
std::map< utility::string_t, utility::string_t > dictionary;
```

I do not understand why it does not see the definition of `object(std::vector< std::pair< utility::string_t, json::value > >)` (I have included `cpprest/json.h`)?

Comment: What is `dictionary`? How is it declared? What is `utility::string_t`? How is it declared?

Comment: What is `utility::string_t`? Is it perhaps a typedef to `std::string`?

Comment: But `object`'s constructor looks like this: `object(std::vector<std::pair<::utility::string_t, value>> fields, bool keep_order = false)`. Why do I get undefined reference error?

Comment: Because you haven't defined that constructor (or haven't linked to the file it's defined in).

Comment: It should be in cpprest/json.h that I have included...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do not understand why doesn't it see that answer has no std::string?

Obviously `utility::string_t` is a typedef for `std::string` and the compiler is showing the real type, not the typedef name (although in this case the *real* name is `std::basic_string<char>`, but the compiler has a special rule to show that as the more common name `std::string`).

Comment: The *real* real name is `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>` ;)